# Is there a linter to help write good Mathematica code?

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, syntax

I don't do much real programming, but I've recently been turned on to [Atom](https://atom.io/), which has [linter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30339671/1818245) plugins for [over 50 languages](http://atomlinter.github.io/) to make coding easier (most drawing on pre-existing lint-like programs).

In other languages, linters help me learn about operator precedence (unnecessary parentheses), good programming styles/techniques, and get warnings about code that may not have been intended. Is there something along these lines for Mathematica?

If not, is there a reason why not? At first glance it seems like a number of the suggestions/tips I pick up from reading answers here could be automated. For example, maybe the Mathematica linter would remind you to memoize your functions with `f[n_]:=f[n]=` if that setting is turned on.

**Edit:** For a couple days in November 2016 there was work on a linter for Atom for Mathematica [on github](https://github.com/teedr/linter-mathematica/releases), but the project seems to have died quickly and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I wonder if you could make something like this get your features? http://mathematicaplugin.halirutan.de/

Comment: How is this different from the little popups that appear over each command when you hover the mouse? Or the "context sensitive" help?

Comment: Like bill s I would say that a very strong capability along the lines you describe already exists in _Mathematica_.

Comment: I don't know of one, but it would be cool to have warnings for private symbols that start with an uppercase letter, implicit multiplications at line boundaries, and unlocalized iterator variables in `Table` constructs within functions (just to name the first few ideas that popped into my head).  The [pitfalls](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/142) post would be an excellent source of inspiration for checks to implement.  I wonder if a bit of spelunking would turn up a way to extend the front-end's existing bare-bone checks?

Comment: @WReach Ideally this is what Workbench would do if version 3 ever comes out of beta.

Answer (score 46):

I am a developer at Wolfram Research and I have been working on linter technology that I think would be nice to share publicly.

There are 2 paclets on the public paclet server that you can download and use for finding problems with WL code.

The two paclets you will need are CodeParser and CodeInspector:

```
In[1]:= PacletInstall["CodeParser"]
Out[1]= PacletObject[CodeParser,1.0,<>]

In[2]:= PacletInstall["CodeInspector"]
Out[2]= Paclet[CodeInspector,1.0,<>]
```

The CodeParser paclet provides functions for parsing WL code and returning syntax trees with interesting metadata attached, such as file and line information.

The CodeInspector paclet uses CodeParser and provides functions for scanning WL code and finding problems and reporting them.

Here is a demo of using the CodeInspector paclet.

First, load the CodeInspector` package:

```
Needs["CodeInspector`"]
```

Next, take a snippet of code that you are interested in linting.

```
code = "Which[a, b, a, b]";
```

Use `CodeInspect` to get a `List` of `InspectionObject`s:

```
lints = CodeInspect[code];
```

The `InspectionObject`s are interesting by themselves, but it would be nice to see them formatted within lines of the source code.

```
CodeInspectSummarize[code]
```

The report shows formatted lines that you can mouse over to see the problem descriptions.

I included a screenshot to better show the result.

[image: summary of code linting]

It is possible to also scan files with by doing `CodeInspect[File[file]]`

Both the parser and linter are open-sourced here:

https://github.com/WolframResearch/codeparser

https://github.com/WolframResearch/codeinspector

I hope you enjoy using them!

Comment: When you solicit the community, you may want to look at things like the current "hot meta post" [Linting - Code analysis for bugs, errors and style issues in the Wolfram Language](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2435/4616)

Comment: I find it limiting that it won't run on files containing non-ASCII characters. Many of my source files contain such characters in comments. When using any other editor than the FE, this is the only way to include accented (or non-Roman) letters.  It would be great if the linter could somehow still do its job and only provide a *warning* instead of failing completely.

Comment: There seem to be some problems with `LintString` on my machine (macOS, M11.3). The first example from the docs returns `{}`: `str = "1+f[,2]"; lints = LintString[str]` There are also discrepancies between `LintFile` and `LintString`: the former returns more warnings than the latter. Finally, `LintFileReport` seems to return an empty list in the situations I tried, even though `LintFile` did give a non-empty list of lints.

Comment: [This is the file I tried,](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/blob/master/IGraphM/Trees.m) after removing the non-ASCII characters. That's easy to do by opening and re-saving the file with the FE. There are warnings about a mis-use of `:`. The output of `LintFile` does not refer to the location within the file in a clear way, and I hoped that `LintFileReport` would give me this information.

Comment: I figured out that `LintFileReport` does not give me all results because of the 
 `"SeverityExclusions"` option, so that was an easy fix.  Other comments: please support file names wrapped in `File`, and please add file name auto-completion to `LineFile`.

Comment: This seems really cool! Thanks for sharing. I look forward to future updates. In the meantime, let me start running this on my files...

Comment: And, of course, the first thing I should have said is that having these tools is really great!  Thanks for all your work. :-)

Comment: Big +1, Have you considered putting it e.g. on GitHub? @Szabolcs would have more space for issues :)

Comment: @MarkS. Thank you for the link.

@Szabolcs Thank you for the comments. The current limitation to ASCII characters is a consequence of using `RunProcess`. This will be fixed in the next update of AST which will use LibraryLink.

In general, handing the contents of a file to `LintString` is not equivalent to `LintFile`. Compare this with `ToExpression["a\nb"]`, which returns only `b`, and `ParseString["a\nb"]` which returns only the node for `b`. Though this could possibly be made to work in the future.

@Kuba We are working on getting this on GitHub in the near future.

Comment: @brenton Thanks for the explanation about `LintString`/`LintFile`, it makes sense now. As for non-ASCII characters, I think it is still very useful to warn about them, as they can cause trouble (they did for me). Could you update the post when the new version is available?

Comment: Hi @brenton, it is nice to see this great work. I am currently implementing a language server for Wolfram Language hosted at https://github.com/kenkangxgwe/lsp-wl, and would like to use your AST and Lint paclets. But since your paclets are in their experimental stages, it might be more convenient if you could share a code repo so maybe I can track their updates or even somehow contribute to them.

Comment: The talk at the Wolfram Tech Conference 2019 was useful and will likely be posted online shortly.

Comment: The CodeInspector has now been made available on GitHub:
https://github.com/WolframResearch/codeinspector