# Highlighting values in a dataset

Tags: dataset

I have a question regarding highlighting severals values in (column of) a dataset. Here a simple example:

```
names = StringJoin["name", #] & /@ ToString /@ Range[9];

values = RandomInteger[100, 9];
```

and then

```
ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[{"name", "value"} -> #] & /@ ({names, 
 values}\[Transpose])]
```

Now we have something like:

[image]

I now can highlight values in the Dataset with:

```
    highLight1[x_] := Which[x < 0.9*50, Style[x, Blue],
   x > 1.1*50, Style[x, Red],
   True, x];
```

Now the following does what I desire, it applies a function to a column of the dataset:

```
ds[All, {"value" -> highLight1}]
```

[image]

What I could not manage to do is to make the highlighting work with a parameter, something like

```
    Clear highLight;
highLight[x_, limit_] := Which[x < 0.9*limit, Style[x, Blue],
   x > 1.1*limit, Style[x, Red],
   True, x];
```

This does not work, even when I use a modified version which accepts a list as x_ in the `highlight1` function.

[image]

So the question is, whether there is a clean and simple way to get the values highlighted in this "parametrized" way? (Maybe it is just simple and I do not see it...)

Comment: Just a precedence issue: `ds[All, {"value" -> (highLight[#, 50] &)}]`

Comment: @Karsten7.: Thank you! You saved my day. It is that simple (shame on me) but I did not see this issue... and then tried a lot of (funny) things ;-)

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html#25791

Comment: This would be a job for the [linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)), if Mathematica [would have one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112753/18476).